# Action Bar Items with Icon & Text

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Is there a way to display the icon and the text in the action bar? I have tried using the showAsAction attribute in the xml file by setting it to "always|withText" and "ifRoom|withText" but neither works unless the phone is in landscape mode.

There is a lot of unused space since I removed the title from the Action Bar as well but that space isn't being used.

How do I make sure that both the icon and the text display even in portrait mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I make sure that both the icon and the text display even in portrait mode?

You don't. The decision for whether or not to show the text is up to the implementation of the action bar, based on its own algorithms.

If you think that it can be improved, feel free to create a sample project that demonstrates the inefficiency and post an enhancement request to http://b.android.com.

Of course, you are welcome to use your own custom action layout or action class instead of the stock action items, and on those you can display whatever you want. Matching the look and feel of the existing action items may be a bit tricky, and you'll have to implement your own smarts for determining when you do not have room for the text.

Comment: Is there a way to position the items more effectively since there is so much unused space due to the elimination of the title?

Comment: @dMehta: You are welcome to find other ways of using the space, such as adding drop-down list navigation or something. However, the decision of what action items show up in the bar (versus the overflow), whether those action items show text or not, and so forth is up to the implementation of the action bar.